# Peer to Peer - When will it be available?

Tags: javascript

Is this possible?  Will this be possible any time soon?

Here is [advanced Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&lr=&safe=off&tbs=qdr%3Ay&q=javascript%20advanced%20search&oq=javascript%20advanced%20search&aq=f&aqi=g1g-K1&aql=&gs_l=serp.3..0j0i30.84129.95890.0.96145.31.17.3.11.13.0.87.1072.17.17.0...0.0.F1_eRMT-UYA&pbx=1&biw=1214&bih=885&cad=cbv&sei=cY7HT7SZCunb0QHxjfGwDw#hl=en&lr=&safe=off&tbs=qdr:y&sclient=psy-ab&q=javascript+websockets+peer+to+peer&oq=javascript+websockets+peer+to+peer&aq=f&aqi=q-A1&aql=&gs_l=serp.3..33i29.2993.7674.0.7836.23.18.5.0.0.0.79.1238.18.18.0...0.0.AsTdCCD1ssM&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=368c51b11e74cdf8&biw=1214&bih=885), on JavaScript websockets peer to peer

Filtered for last year only.

**Related SO by Year**

[2009 post - peer to peer web sockets is planned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032006/will-html5-allow-web-apps-to-make-peer-to-peer-http-connections)

[2011 post - I don't think it is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018544/can-you-connect-client-to-client-via-web-sockets-without-touching-the-server)

[2011 Post - Not Possible + Motherload of more links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022383/how-to-make-a-browser-to-browser-peer-to-peer-connection)

[2011 Post - WebRTC on Horizon - The Best answer so far](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993042/is-webrtc-implemented-in-any-browsers-yet)

For the current status check [the webrtc site](http://www.webrtc.org/) maintained By Google...this might provide an understanding of when you can switch from peer to proxy to peer....to peer to peer.

Comment: Also related: [Will html 5 allow web apps to make peer to peer http connections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032006/will-html5-allow-web-apps-to-make-peer-to-peer-http-connections). Unrelated, love your username.

Comment: Hope it is true, but doubt that it is. I asked this same question to my buds yesterday. Some times in game making, there is so much communication that goes through the server, and it would be nice to by pass it and just go straight to the device. Anywho... fingers crossed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a browser to browser (peer to peer) connection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022383/how-to-make-a-browser-to-browser-peer-to-peer-connection)

Comment: The clusters they mostly come at night

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7933140/1002469)--look for "WebRTC" near the bottom.

What you are talking about is not part of the Websockets specification but something called WebRTC, specifically the Peer-to-Peer Data API.

No browser implements it yet, but Chrome and Firefox have started to implement parts of WebRTC and probably will implement this too.